# Google cloud load balancer with external server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I want to know if it is possible link the Google Cloud load balancer to an external server - a server hosted outside of Google Cloud?

So the load balancer might link to a Google Cloud instance but also an external server.

Comment: I can't see any option like that. The load balancer has one or more backend services, which are tied to instance groups or Cloud Storage Buckets. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/backend-service

Answer (score 1):

Not by attaching directly to the load balancer but you can add a backend service consisting of an auto scalable instance group hosted on google cloud which will proxy the incoming traffic to the external server. This will result in the overhead of billing and maintenance of such an auto-scalable group of instances. Hence, depending on the volume of traffic you are handling another approach can be to route traffic via existing backend service i.e. configure the servers running in your existing backend service by adding appropriate conditions(path based routing etc.) and proxy to the external server instead of relying on Google HTTP Load Balancer to perform the path based routing part.

Answer (score 0):

In 2021, you can use an Internet network endpoint group backend with Internet Network Endpoint Group (External backends): https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/internet-neg-concepts

See also https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-external-backend-internet-neg